# What if I put two kinds of encoded strings, say utf-8 and utf-16, in one file?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

In Python, for example:

```
f = open('test','w')
f.write('this is a test\n'.encode('utf-16'))
f.write('another test\n'.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

That file gets messy when I re-open it:

```
f = open("test")
print f.readline().decode('utf-16')  # it leads to UnicodeDecodeError
print f.readline().decode('utf-8')   # it works fine
```

However if I keep the texts encoded in one style (say utf-16 only), it could read back ok.
So I'm guessing mixing two types of encoding in the same file is wrong and couldn't be decoded back, even if I do know the encoding rules of each specific string? Any suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Not at all sure how readLine() is supposed to detect the line-ending when you don't know if it is UTF-8 or UTF-16. If you can get that fixed, it would probably work. But why?

Comment: Your code would work on Big Endian systems; `'\n'.encode('utf-16-be')` == `'\x00\n'`so .readline would actually include the extra byte.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah it really works if I change the encoding rules to 'utf-16-be', but could you tell me why it works when pointing out big-endian BOM? I've tried 'utf-16-le', but it failed. And if I just use 'utf-16', does it mean it equals to 'utf-16-le'?? Thank you!

Comment: I've written up an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually a bad idea, but in your case it doesn't work because you encode newlines as well.

In UTF-16, *every* character is encoded to two bytes, including the newline you wrote. Because you read your file line by line, python will give you all data from the file up to the next newline byte, but in UTF-16 that could mean that one of the two bytes is still included in the returned data resulting in an incomplete UTF-16 byte stream.

To understand this, you need to understand UTF-16 encoding in more detail. When writing 16-bit data as 2 bytes of 8 bits, computers need to decide which byte to write to the file first. This decision can go two ways, and is called [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess); like Gulliver's Lilliputs, computer systems prefer either Big or Little endian ordering.

An UTF-16 data stream is thus written in one of two orderings, and a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or "BOM" is written first to flag which one was choosen.

Your newline is thus either encoded as `'\n\x00'` or `'\x00\n'`, and on reading that null byte (`\x00`) is either part of the UTF-16 data you decode, or the UTF-8 data (where it is ignored). So, if you encode UTF-16 as big endian, things work (but you have a stray null byte), but if you encode as little endian, things break.

Basically, encoded data should be treated strictly as binary data and you should use a different method to delineate different pieces of encoded text, *or* you should only use encodings where newlines are strictly encoded as newlines.

I'd use a length prefix, read that first, then read that number of bytes from the file for each encoded piece of data.

```
>>> import struct
>>> f = open('test', 'wb')
>>> entry1 = 'this is a test\n'.encode('utf-16')
>>> struct.pack('!h', len(entry1)))
>>> f.write(entry1)
>>> entry2 = 'another test\n'.encode('utf-8')
>>> f.write(struct.pack('!h', len(entry2)))
>>> f.write(entry2)
>>> f.close()
```

I've used the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to write fixed-length length data. Note that I write the file as binary, too.

Reading:

```
>>> f = open('test', 'rb')
>>> fieldsize = struct.calcsize('!h')
>>> length = struct.unpack('!h', f.read(fieldsize))[0]
>>> print f.read(length).decode('utf-16')
this is a test

>>> length = struct.unpack('!h', f.read(fieldsize))[0]
>>> print f.read(length).decode('utf-8')
another test

>>>
```

Again the file is opened in binary mode.

In a real-life application you probably have to include the encoding information per entry as well.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, and I'll refer to the struct part of python :)

Answer (score 1):

A working version of your code. Basically don't encode the newlines, and remove them when call readline() method:

```
f = open('test','w')
f.write('this is a test'.encode('utf-16'))
f.write("\n")
f.write('another test'.encode('utf-8'))
f.write("\n")
f.close()

f = open("test")
print f.readline().strip("\n").decode('utf-16')
print f.readline().strip("\n").decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: And what if the data to write includes newlines? `u'this is an\nexample with paragrahs'`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use some markers at the beginning of the line ?

```
>>> f = open('test','w')
f.write('16 - this is a test\n'.encode('utf-16'))
f.write('8 - another test\n'.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
>>> f = open('test')
>>> for line in f:
    if line.startswith('8 - '):
        print line.replace('8 - ', '').decode('utf-8')
    elif line.startswith('16'):
        print line.replace('16 - ', '').decode('utf-16')
```

Comment: Nope, UTF-16 encodes line endings too (2 bytes), so you'd need to make sure you use Big Endian encoding for this to work at all with python's line-ending support.

Answer (score 0):

It is general accepted that using two different encodings in the same file is a bad idea. The only time I think it could be useful is if you had a structured file(e.g. XML. JSON, etc) in which an element could have an encoding specified.

```
<entries>
    <entry encoding="utf-16">
        <text>私</text>
        <meaning>I, myself</meaning>
    </entry>
    <entry encoding="utf-8">
        <text>あなた</text>
        <meaning>you, yourself</meaning>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Pseudo-code:

```
for entry in entries:
    text += entry.text.decode(entry.encoding)
```

Also, your example is failing because your system is Little Endian and readline is breaking the line in the middle of a utf-16 character. This is resulting in the first line to be missing the last \x00 and the last line to be prepended with the \x00 from the utf-16 line. Here is quick fix:

```
f = open("test")
print (f.readline()+'\x00').decode('utf-16')  # it leads to UnicodeDecodeError
print f.readline()[1:].decode('utf-8')   # it works fine
```

Comment: That is not be valid XML, though, right? Parsers would croak.

Comment: I tweaked it slightly, it was never intended to be valid, just an example.